# How to update auto completion suggestions of QCompleter in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am adding auto completer to QTextEdit and I am trying to refresh QCompleter class after appending a suggestion to the `auto_completion_list` in the AutoCompleter class and then I need to refresh or update suggestions to QCompleter. How to do that?

Here is my code:

```
class AutoCompleter(QCompleter):
    insertText = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.auto_completion_list = ['Suggestion1','Suggestion2','Suggestion3']
        super().__init__(self.auto_completion_list, parent)
        self._parent = parent
        self.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
        self.popup().setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet())
        self.popup().setFixedSize(QSize(125,70))
        self.popup().setFont(QFont("Consolas",11))
        self.highlighted.connect(self.setHighlighted)
    def add(self,suggestion):
        #What Should I do here After appending keyword to refresh QCompleter? 
        self.auto_completion_list.append(keyword)
    def setHighlighted(self, text):
        self.lastSelected = text
    def getSelected(self):
        return self.lastSelected
class Editor(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.completer = AutoCompleter()
        self.completer.setWidget(self)
        self.completer.insertText.connect(self.insertCompletion)
    def insertCompletion(self, completion):
        tc = self.textCursor()
        extra = (len(completion) - len(self.completer.completionPrefix()))
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.Left)
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfWord)
        tc.insertText(completion[-extra:])
        self.setTextCursor(tc)
        self.completer.popup().hide()
    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        if self.completer:
            self.completer.setWidget(self)
        QTextEdit.focusInEvent(self, event)
    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        tc = self.textCursor()
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Tab:
            if self.completer.popup().isVisible():
                self.completer.insertText.emit(self.completer.getSelected())
                self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
            else:
                tc = self.textCursor()
                tc.insertText("    ")
            return
        QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
        tc.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)
        cr = self.cursorRect()

        if len(tc.selectedText()) > 0:
            self.completer.setCompletionPrefix(tc.selectedText())
            popup = self.completer.popup()
            popup.setCurrentIndex(self.completer.completionModel().index(0,0))

            cr.setWidth(self.completer.popup().sizeHintForColumn(0) 
            + self.completer.popup().verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width())
            self.completer.complete(cr)
        else:
            self.completer.popup().hide()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QCompleter uses a model, and when initialized with a list of strings, that is a QStringListModel. You can update the list using [`setStringList()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html#setStringList):

```
class AutoCompleter(QCompleter):
    # ...
    def add(self, suggestion):
        self.auto_completion_list.append(suggestion)
        self.model().setStringList(self.auto_completion_list)
```